# How to make Terraform to read AWS Credentials file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform-provider-aws, aws-credentials, terraform-aws-modules

I am trying to create an AWS S3 bucket using terraform and this is my code:

```
provider "aws" {
  profile = "default"
  region  = "ap-south-1"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "first_tf" {
  bucket = "svk-pl-2909202022"
  acl    = "private"
}
```

I have manually created the "Credentials" file using Notepad and also removed the ".txt" extension using Powershell and stored that file in `C:\Users\terraform\.aws`, and that file is like this:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=**************
aws_secret_access_key=************
```

But when I try to run `terraform plan`, I get an error which says

> ERROR: error configuring Terraform AWS Provider: no valid credential sources for Terraform AWS Provider found

Then, I also tried to create that "Credentials" file by installing AWS CLI, I ran the command

```
aws configure --profile terraform
```

where `terraform` was my username. So, it asked me to enter `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key`. and after entering all the credentials, I ran the command `terraform init`, which ran successfully but when I ran `terraform plan`, it shows the error again which says:

> ERROR: error configuring Terraform AWS Provider: no valid credential sources for Terraform AWS Provider found

Comment: Just wanted to add, as there are not many answers for this provider, In my case (`alicloud`) the format of the credential files was suppose to be `json`-like vs `ini`-like.

This is also being stated in the documentation of the `provider` itself.
in my case, this was the reason that the file has been ignored

Answer (score 53, accepted):

When you create a profile manually

```
provider "aws" {
  region                  = "your region"
  shared_credentials_file = "path_file_credentials like C:\Users\terraform\.aws\credentials"
  profile                 = "profile_name"
}
```

When you don't want to put your shared file manually

That needs to be in this path `%USERPROFILE%.aws\credentials`

```
provider "aws" {
  region                  = "your region"
  profile                 = "profile_name"
}
```

If you want to put your credentials in a tf file

```
provider "aws" {
  region     = "us-west-2"
  access_key = "my-access-key"
  secret_key = "my-secret-key"
}
```

Comment: Since version 4.0.0 of the AWS provider the param to specify the credentials file is called `shared_credentials_files` (mind the plural) and it expects a list. Hence, it should be `shared_credentials_files = ["path_to_credentials_file"]`. See [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/guides/version-4-upgrade).

Comment: I would recommend against the 3rd option of adding the credentials inside the provider block, as this will likely be committed to a repository, and it is a security risk exposing your credentials this way.

Comment: if using profile="profile_name" the profile has a region so what is region="your region for??   what if they are different?

Answer (score 49):

I've spent quite a bit of time trying to figure out how to get Terraform to read ~/.aws/credentials. The only option that worked for me was specifying AWS_PROFILE environment var to point it to the specific section of the credentials file.

```
AWS_PROFILE=prod terraform plan
```

or

```
export AWS_PROFILE=prod 
terraform plan
```

The fact that the **shared_credentials_file** and/or the **profile** options in the provider section get ignored looks like a bug to me.

Comment: I've come to the same conclusion. Any updates on this?

Comment: If your issue is pertaining to backend configuration for the state file, I've come across this issue: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/13589
; running `terraform init -reconfigure` solved the issue for me

Comment: Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65647873/6867065) answer this behavior is not a bug but it results from the hierarchy which Terraform follows while deriving configuration (i.e., env variables, like `AWS_PROFILE`, have higher priority than shared configuration files).

Answer (score 3):

The path where you are storing the credentials file is wrong.

**C:\Users\your-username\.aws**

You can add these below files in the above location.

**credentials**

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = your access key
aws_secret_access_key = your secret key
```

**config**

```
[default]
region=ap-south-1
```

And you don't need to configure any thing into terraform or python if you're using boto3. Terraform and boto3 will automatically find the desired credentials file.

Answer (score 3):

You have to set up a custom section in your credentials file with the command

```
aws configure --profile=prod
```

in order to use env variable like this.

Answer (score 2):

when you have AWS cli already installed  in local then go to  config file path: `%USERPROFILE%\.aws\credentials`
Update Credentials as below:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = "xxxxx"
aws_secret_access_key = "xxxxx"
region= us-east-1
```