# Terraform not using provided AWS profile?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'll update later, but for now...

```
$ terraform --version
Terraform v0.12.17
+ provider.aws v3.23.0
```

I have an AWS profile set in my `./aws/credentials` and `~/.aws/config` files, like so...

```
~/.aws/credentials
[default]
aws_access_key_id=****
aws_secret_access_key=****

[myprofile]
aws_access_key_id=****
aws_secret_access_key=****

~/.aws/config
[default]
region=us-east-1
output=json

[profile myprofile]
region=us-east-1
output=json
```

In my Terraform plan, I have

```
provider "aws" {
  region  = "us-east-1"
  profile = "myprofile"
}

terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.12.17, < 0.13"
}

resource "aws_vpc" "vpc" {
  cidr_block = "10.123.123.0/24"

  tags = {
    Name = "test_vpc"
  }
}

output "vpc_id" {
  value = aws_vpc.vpc.id
}
```

And I have a plan that creates a VPC, so I do

```
$ export AWS_PROFILE=myprofile
$ terraform apply
Apply complete! Resources: 1 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

module_vpc_id = vpc-123456abced
```

As you can see the plan creates the VPC, however, the VPC doesn't get created in the `myprofile` account but in the `default` account. I know so because 1) I don't see it in the `myprofile` account, and 2) when I destroy the plan, it shows the `owner_id` as the `default` account number. Why?

**Update:** Note if I add the `access_key` and `secret_key` key/value pairs in my `provider {}` block, it creates the VPC in the correct account. Of course I don't wanna do this, but just wanted to prove that the script indeed works with the `myprofile` account.

**Update:** Note the following commands return nothing (blanks)

```
$ echo $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
$ echo $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
```

and running `env` doesn't show those variables.

Comment: The `profile` is third in [priority](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs#authentication), behind ENV variables and static credentails. Can you verify that you don't have any ENV variables  set when you try to use profile?

Comment: Yeah that's the first thing I tried (I'll update post). So both `echo $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `echo $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` return nothing.

Comment: And what about the `AWS_PROFILE`?

Comment: @Marcin that was it, AWS_PROFILE was defined. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to hear it worked out. If you don't mind, I will provide an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was caused by having `AWS_PROFILE` env variable set. According to [TF docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs#authentication), the variable has higher priority then `Shared credentials/configuration file`:

- Static credentials
- Environment variables
- Shared credentials/configuration file
- CodeBuild, ECS, and EKS Roles
- EC2 Instance Metadata Service (IMDS and IMDSv2)

Comment: I had a similar problem with the init command, but `AWS_PROFILE` was not an ENV variable in my shell. Also,  my AWS credentials and config were set up correctly (just like @chris f), but I had to run my command: `AWS_PROFILE=profilename terraform init` -- in order for it to work.

Comment: This just worked for me too, but it doesn't make sense. Why does the line: profile = "my-aws-profile"  doesn't work? I'm still trying to understand. I will answer here again if I find out about it.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else stuck in this and spending countless hours to figure things out, I realized the `profile` you place in the `provider "aws"` [has nothing to do with the one in the `backend "s3"` block](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/settings/backends/s3#profile).

In short, you will need to specify the profile in both places just like the following.

```ini
provider "aws" {
  profile = "my-aws-profile" # <- this is usual practice
  region  = "eu-central-1"
}

terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    profile        = "my-aws-profile" # <- notice the duplication here
    bucket         = "my-terraform-state-bucket"
    key            = "path/to/terraform.tfstate"
    region         = "eu-central-1"
    encrypt        = true
    dynamodb_table = "terraform-state-lock"
  }
}
```

The sad part is that you cannot even put it in a `locals` block to avoid duplication.

You may however be able to get around this using tools like Terragrunt!